# Pointers in Swift

Tags: swift, pointers, unsafe-pointers, unsafemutablepointer

I'm trying to understand the use of pointers in Swift, in particular: `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer` and `UnsafeRaw[Mutable]Pointer`. I have several questions on the subject.

1. Is `UnsafePointer <T>` equal to `const T * Pointer` in ? and `UnsafeMutablePointer <T>` is equal to `T * Pointer` in C?
2. What is the difference between `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer` and `UnsafeRaw[Mutable]Pointer`?
3. Why does this compile

```
func receive(pointer: UnsafePointer<Int> ) {
    print("param value is: \(pointer.pointee)")
}

var a: Int = 1
receive(pointer: &a) // prints 1
```

but this gives me an error?

```
var a: Int = 1
var pointer: UnsafePointer<Int> = &a // error : Cannot pass immutable value of type 'Int' as inout argument
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. Is `UnsafePointer <T>` equal to `const T * Pointer` in ? and `UnsafeMutablePointer <T>` is equal to `T * Pointer` in C?

Well, use a bridging header in a Swift app to see how the C pointers are bridged:

```
const int *myInt;
int *myOtherInt;
```

bridges to

```
var myInt: UnsafePointer<Int32>!
var myOtherInt: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!
```

> 2. What is the difference between `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer` and `UnsafeRaw[Mutable]Pointer`?

Swift 3 added a [UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md) to replace the `Unsafe[Mutable]Pointer<Void>` type.  Conversion between pointers of a different type is no longer allowed in Swift.  Instead, the API provides interfaces (`.assumingMemoryBound(to:)` or `.bindMemory(to:capacity:)`) to bind memory to a type.

With regard to question 3, the ampersand means that the variable is `inout`.  <strike>I don't believe you can declare a variable as `inout` unless it is being used by a function that directly modifies the underlying memory, but I'll let the experts correct me.  Instead, use `withUnsafePointer`.</strike>

Thanks to Martin's helpful comment, this syntax was never valid in Swift, and there is no safe way to create "free pointers" to Swift variables.

Comment: `var pointer: UnsafePointer<Int> = &a` was never valid, and your "workaround" is unsafe: The pointer passed to the closure of `withUnsafePointer` is only valid during the execution of the closure. It must not be passed to the outside of the closure. – You *cannot* (safely) pass pointers  to Swift variables freely around.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I'll edit my answer.  Not really clear what the OP wanted, so I wasn't sure if they wanted safe/unsafe behavior.  But it's clear they're new to pointers, better to just remove any unsafe behavior entirely.